# systemctl commands under WSL

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, systemctl

I am running Ubuntu inside Windows using WSL.
I receive the following errors when I run scripts with systemctl command:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Do you know what are the equivalent of the following systemctl commands I can run within  WSL?

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl reset-failed
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no equivalent commands. WSL (both 1 & 2) do not run any init system like Systemd, OpenRC or whatever. WSL 2 distributions run as “containers” that are mostly like Docker containers. If we disregard the plumbing, they only start shell instances as you open terminals.

You can run nested containers (e.g. using `systemd-nspawn`) inside WSL 2 that could then run Systemd (or anything else that might want PID 1).

Depending on what you’re trying to do, a full VM may be a more suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Reusing some of the following from my [Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986), but the commands you are asking about are quite different, so I'll modify this answer a bit.  Still, you might want to read that Ask Ubuntu answer as well for some more information.

##### The problem

In general, when you see *either* of the following two messages:

- `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.`
- `Failed to connect to bus: Host is down`

(As well as a few others)

Then it's typically the same root cause.

The core problem is that WSL doesn't use Systemd, even in distributions such as Ubuntu (and most others) where it is the default.  Instead, WSL currently uses its own `/init` process as PID 1, which performs a few WSL-specific tasks that I mention in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1328686/1165986) (so I won't repeat them here).

The commands that you refer to specifically are for *reloading* Systemd units.  Since there are no Systemd units running under WSL anyway, there's really not much point to trying to reload them.

I'm taking a guess here, but I would assume you are trying to *reload* because there's some unit/service that you expect to be running that isn't.  This, of course, is because Systemd isn't running.

See the linked answer for information on how to start services under Ubuntu on WSL.

Something I don't mention in that particular answer is around process supervision in general (which `daemon-reload` and `reset-failed` would apply to).  If you do want some basic process supervision on Ubuntu, I'd recommend looking into [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org).  It can be easily installed on Ubuntu (unlike some other process supervisors which double as `init` systems).  You do have to create your own configuration, but the syntax is fairly straightforward for most services.